# Tracking custom events in FB analytics

Tags: facebook, analytics, facebook-ads-api, web-analytics

Facebook analytics has their 9 event types: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/v2.5

But what about custom events?

The docs say that custom events can only be used to build custom audiences. How can you measure custom events that are outside the 9 built-in types in order to measure the effectiveness of your an ad?

Answer (score 3):

I just added a custom event in the fbq function like so `fbq('track', 'ViewEnHomePage’)`. It's working, custom events are tracked, but in developers console I get the error that it is the unknown event. I actually landed on this question in search how to debug it, so if you don't have a too demanding client custom event like this should work.

**EDIT**
Looked over the link you provided and there is a custom event reporting

```
fbq('trackCustom', '<CustomEventName>', {
    custom_param1: 'ABC',
    custom_param2: 123,
    value: 10.00,
    currency: 'USD'
});
```

Would this work?